# Templated User Control - Event firing before Initialization?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a rather complex layout that looks something like this:

1. Page
2. Within the Page, Templated UserControl A
3. Within the template defined by the page, UserControl B
4. Within UserControl B, ASPxUploadControl

The templates for UserControl A are loaded as follows:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        if (CommandsTemplate != null)
        {
            SimpleDataItemContainer commandsContainer = new SimpleDataItemContainer(CurrentSurvey);
            CommandsTemplate.InstantiateIn(commandsContainer);
            CommandsPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(commandsContainer);
        }

        DataBind();
        LayoutDataBound?.Invoke(this, null);
}
```

The page then picks up on the `LayoutDataBound` event to set a property on `UserControl` B.   This all works well on the initial load and I can see the required property value on `UserControl` B, however when `ASPxUploadControl` triggers a postback by selecting '`Upload`' the event handler `UploadControl_FileUploadComplete` gets fired as soon the commandsTemplate gets rebuilt and before `DataBind()`.

Since that method requires the property that will be set by the `LayoutDataBound` event handler the entire process falls in a heap.

I have spent a great deal of time trying to set up the templated controls early enough in the life cycle that they don't need to be recreated on page load figuring that the previously set property value would then be available in the `ViewState` but I haven't had any success.  If I don't recreate the controls each load then they are not visible.

Is anyone able to point me at what I am doing wrong here?